# 1 bone stuck in pose mode rotating around 1 end

Tags: rigging

I am new to rigs and animations and I wanted to work out some hands animations for a FP game I am working on. The bones are taken from the basic rig if I remember (I.E. because I started it almost like a month ago and came back to it because I thought it was not what I wanted at start but it looks ok now :D ). My problem is that the I don't remember what I've done to it, because as you can see, one of the bones is Yellow and it doesn't move, only rotate around the lower end. It can be deformed from the Inspector but the problem is the lower end is still stuck in place. I looked through it and nothing at the first sight is locked. Any help will be apreciated. What i want to do is unlock it because the hand can't go up because the wrist will go up with the hand, but the arm is stuck down because of that.
Also trying to rotate the certain bone, makes the higher part of the arm go down.
[image: The yellow bone is the problematic one]

Comment: green bone means it has a constraint, probably an IK constraint, this bone must be controlled by another one, select it and check in the Bone Constraint tab to see what is the controller

Comment: You are right, it had an IK constraint, i just used f3 and cleared it, and now it works like the others. Thank you very much for the help !!!!

Comment: you cleared it but maybe it was somehow useful?

Comment: It might have been indeed, but what i wanted was a slash animation with the sword, and that constraint prevented me from animating it so it would look somehow natural

Comment: I understand or at least i think i understand what you want to say, that it should have some constraints so it doesn't look like the bones are going too far from the body, but It was placed wrong anyway, it rotated around the bottom one, which made it impossible to move the hand upwards